# How to make a recovered Ubuntu file system bootable again?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, backup, grub

I have an old backup of an Ubuntu 16.04 system that I want to be brought back online on a computer. The backup is just a tar archive of the entire root filesystem, `/`.

After extracting the archives into a directory I can chroot into the system with `sudo chroot /path/to/old_system` (miraculously we still have the passwords :p) and everything seems in order.

**Question**

Now how do I make a bootable system from this extracted file system?

**What I've tried**

The computer I wanted to use for the old system already had a clean install of Ubuntu 20.04. So I used a live CD to simply replace the entire file system: `mv /* /.new_system/ && mv /.old_system/* /`, which seems to have worked.
But after a reboot, I couldn't start Ubuntu, not with any of the options from the Bios boot menu. So I used the live CD again to try and do a boot repair using `chroot` and `update-grub`. After a reboot, I get into the grub rescue panel, instead of a regular boot, where I am now stuck.
I am posing the question more generally because I am curious about what I should have done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely need to *reinstall* GRUB using `grub-install`, as the tarball only included half of it – after the restore, your `/boot` has GRUB modules for the old version, but your disk's MBR (and the secret post-MBR area) still has a GRUB "core image" (i.e. GRUB kernel) for a much newer version, which is unable to load the required modules.

(Also, make sure to use the correct GRUB platform – if the backup was made on a BIOS system, but the new disk is partitioned for UEFI, then you'll need to install an UEFI version of GRUB as well.)

Alternatively, you could try doing the opposite and replacing just the contents of `/boot/grub` with those from your new backup – again, followed by `update-grub`. A new GRUB should be able to boot old Linux kernels perfectly fine.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Can I easily see of the old system was made in BIOS or UEFI mode?

Comment: Look at what files it has in `/boot/grub` – if there's an "i386-pc" subdirectory, it'll contain GRUB modules for BIOS; if there's "x86_64-uefi", that means UEFI. (Well, I'm assuming Ubuntu 16.04 is recent enough that it'll have GRUB2. The old grub-legacy aka grub0.97 didn't have such subdirectories as it was still made exclusively for BIOS systems.)

Comment: Got it working. The backup was for a BIOS boot system, but the new system was UEFI. So I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04 in BIOS made and extracted the backups over it. I ran `update-grub && update-initramfs -u` in chroot and replaced the now incorrect UUIDs in `etc/fstab`. After a reboot I got back in the system.